# NestJS / TypeOrm / Neo4j : Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NEO4J_DRIVER

Tags: neo4j, nestjs, typeorm

I try to run my NestJs/TypeOrm with Neo4j db but i've got an error :

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NEO4J_DRIVER (?). Please make sure that the argument NEO4J_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the Neo4jModule context.

I don't understand where it come from.

This is my app.module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Neo4jModule } from 'nest-neo4j'
import { PersonModule } from './person/person.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    Neo4jModule.forRootAsync({
      scheme: "neo4j+s",
      host: "db-sp8xxaunnz13icv892y5.graphenedb.com",
      port: 24786,
      username: 'neo4j',
      password: 'ingrid-ticket-capital-spirit-reform-6035'
    }),
    PersonModule,

  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my person.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PersonService } from './person.service';
import { PersonController } from './person.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Person } from './person.entity';
import { Neo4jModule } from 'nest-neo4j/dist';
import { PersonRepository } from './person.entityrepository';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PersonRepository]),
    
      ,
  ],

  providers: [
    PersonService
  ],

  controllers: [
    PersonController
  ]
})
export class PersonModule {}
```

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed driver to install.
Try this npm i neo4j-driver.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, you're using wrong method, instead of `forRootAsync` you should use `forRoot` on `Neo4jModule`

Comment: I try it but i've got this error now :  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PersonRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Connection */ ]
  })
 +1ms

Comment: That's different problem, open new question, mark this as solved, and mark me, I will try to help you there.